# Method in Main program doesn't work when moved to a class

Tags: android

Beginner android question:  I have a method in a Main program that works just fine:

```
 setRadioButtons(answer, value);

... void setRadioButtons (int answer, int value) {
    if (answer == 1)
        ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.C1Button)).setChecked(true);
    else if (answer == 2) ....
```

However this should really be in a class. When I move it to a class it fails:

```
Context context= getApplicationContext();
myQ1.setRadioButtons(answer, value, context);

 ...    public void setRadioButtons(int answer, int value, int context) {
        setContentView(context);
        if (answer == 1)
          ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.C1Button)).setChecked(true);
```

The method call in the Main program shows context underlined in red with the warning:

```
Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'android.content.Context', required: 'int'
```

This must have something to do with context but I really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setRadioButtons(int answer, int value, int context)
```

is expecting an `int, int, int` for parameters. You provided instead an `int, int, Context`

Change the method signature to expect `int, int, context` like so:

```
public void setRadioButtons(int answer, int value, Context context)
```

Comment: None of these suggestion have worked. Not when passing the argument as an int or Context.  Even hard wiring the setContentView statement causes a fatal exception: setContentView(R.layout.layout2). Apparently the layout info gets lost when calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

Context has it's own class.

Anyway, what you should pass to

```
setContentView
```

is not a context, but a layout resource id like

```
R.layout.example
```

Comment: Didn't work even when hard coding setContentView(R.layout.layout2); This causes a fatal exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have declared context as int. Actually it should be Context instance in the method. Change

```
  public void setRadioButtons(int answer, int value, Context context)
```